# Locally computable random permutation

Tags: permutation, pseudo-random-permutation, format-preserving

Let $A$ be a set of size $n$. Given a random seed $s$, I am looking to build a pseudo-random random permutation $\pi_s: A \rightarrow A$ such that $\pi_s(a)$ is fast to compute for every $a \in A$. By "fast to compute" I mean significantly faster than $O(n)$ time, e.g. $O(1)$ or $O(\log n)$ time.

One suggestion is to use Feistel networks or [MiMC](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/492.pdf). Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is the range of $n$ you are interested in? For example, if $n=2^{128}$ then the answer is pretty obvious.

Comment: Format preserving encryption tries to solve exactly what you're asking for; current solutions have issues for tiny $n$ (less than 100, say), however other than that, it appears to work quite well...

Comment: n is between 2^14 and 2^24

Comment: @poncho: The Wikipedia page on format preserving encryption gives an example: :"One simple way to create an FPE algorithm on {0,...,N-1} is to assign a pseudorandom weight to each integer, then sort by weight." The sort takes at least O(N), so this particular scheme seems to fail the "fast to compute" requirement.

Comment: @Randomblue: there exist efficient Format Preserving Encryption algorithms...

Comment: @PaulUszak I'm not interested in the whole permutation, just the mapping of a single element (or a small group of elements).

Comment: If $n$ is between $2^{14}$ and $2^{24}$ then why are you bothering with asymptotics? I suppose you could use a length doubler together with a small block cipher.